# Consider $AX + XA = B$, how many equations and how many unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Here, $A$, $X$, and $B$ are real $n\times n$ matrices.  A and B are given, but X is unknown.

Also, A is symmetric and positive definite, so $A^T = A$ and $z^TAz >0$ for all nonzero $z$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

My question is:  I can easily show that $AX + XA$ is linear in $x$.

but...how many equations and unknowns does it involve?

I wrote out some scratch-work and agree with the solution that it involves $n^2$ unknowns.  However, the solution also says it involves $n^2$ equations.  I'm pretty sure that's wrong, and that there are only $n$ equations involved.

Thanks,

Edit:

How could I show that F(x) = AX + XA is a bijection? I feel like I should be using what's given in the question: that A is real symmetric, positive definite, so then A has real, positive eigenvalues.  Also, A is diagonalizable - orthogonally diagonalizable, in fact - so it has n eigenvectors that form a basis for R^n.  Not sure how to proceed to prove the bijection...

Comment: For further reference, this is known as an instance of the [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I'll definitely have a read - thanks a lot, @Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two matrices are equal if and only if their corresponding elements are equal.  So the matrix equation $AX + XA = B$ yields $n^2$ equations, one for each entry of the two $n \times n$ matrices $AX + XA$ and $B$.

Comment: That's awesome.  I forgot to look at equating the corresponding entries.  Thanks so much, @Jim.

Comment: I edited my question, @Jim, to try and show that AX + XA is a bijection.  Feel free to comment, if you have some time.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The $n^2$ eigenvalues of the linear application $F:X\in M_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow  AX+XA\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are the $(\lambda_i+\lambda_j)_{i,j}$ where $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)_i$. Since $A$ is symmetric $>0$, $F$ is a bijection.

Moreover one may write the equation in this stable form: $-AX-XA=-B$ and the unique solution is $X=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-tA}Be^{-tA}dt$.

EDIT .(answer to Lebron James). 1 $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $n^2$; then $f$ has $n^2$ eigenvalues. We may assume that $A=diag((\lambda_i)_i)$. $f$ admits the $n^2$ elements $(E_{i,j})_{i,j}$ of the canonical basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ as eigenvectors ($f(E_{i,j})=(\lambda_i+\lambda_j)E_{i,j})$. Since the $(\lambda_i)_i$ are $>0$, $f$ has positive eigenvalues and is a bijection and $AX+XA=B$ has a sole solution $X_0$.

2. $X_1=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-tA}Be^{-tA}dt$ exists because $||e^{-tA}Be^{-tA}||=O(e^{-2\lambda t})$ where $\lambda$ is a minimal eigenvalue of $A$ (the matrix $-A$ gives the stability to infinity). If $Y=e^{-tA}Be^{-tA}$, then $Y'=-AY-YA$ and, after integration, $-B=-AX_1-X_1A$, that implies $X_1=X_0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on your explanation, @loupblanc?  For instance, how do we know there are n^2 eigenvalues and the eigenvalues are (lamba_i + lambda_j)_ij?  Also, how do you conclude that since A is symmetric, positive definite, then F is a bijection?

Comment: (I know that A, since it is real, symmetric, positive definite, has n eigenvectors that form a basis for R^n, and these eigenvectors correspond to positive eigenvalues.  I just don't know how F(X) = AX + XA has n^2 eigenvalues, though..)

Comment: Or, since I've already shown that F(x) is a linear operator, I only need to show that F is injective, and then we get that F is surjective and hence bijective for free (since we're mapping the space into itself).  So, if F(X) = AX + XA = 0, then it must have trivial kernel, i.e., X must be 0.  How can I proceed from here?  I know I'd most likely have to use the fact that A is S.P.D.

Comment: I was able to figure out the injective proof and show that F is a bijection, @loupblanc.  Would you mind elaborating on your way of solving for that unique X via the stable form?  Thanks in advance,